# How to convert tf format images from uint8 to numpy array python

Tags: python-3.x, type-conversion, numpy-ndarray

I have imgs and labels which i decoded from tf record. I want to visualize them.

for this I have to convert it from uint8 to numpy.

```js
<tf.Tensor: shape=(224, 224, 3), dtype=uint8, numpy=
array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        ...,
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]],


  [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]]], dtype=uint8)>
```

Thats what it shows when i print imgs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply run the following command.

```
imgs,labels = imgs.numpy(), labels.numpy()
```

it convert imgs and labels into numpy.